# How to get the selected SubItem index in a Listview and highlight it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, selection

I am trying to get the selected ListViewItem index, so that when the user clicks on a particular row, such as row 2, I want the clicked cell's text to be set to a TextBox's text.

I also want to highlight only this cell, ideally using the regular selection ListView uses, or do I need to create a class that inherits from ListView to do this?

Something like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not using a `DataGridView`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: it didn't occur to me to use DGV, I guess I use listviews a lot more for simplicity.

Comment: Starting from .NET 2.0 I never used a ListView again to show a list like this. Assuming you have a list of items, then showing them in DataGridView is as easy as `dataGridView1.DataSource = list;` or what you are going to do here is as simple as `dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;`. I believe it's better to consider it as an option for your future applications :)

Comment: However, if you need some features like switching mode to thumbnail, etc or showing groups, then you need to stick to ListVIew.

Comment: @Reza: Oh I see, in my case, I only update a few cells live that shows current crypto prices and leave the rest, so can DGV do this? Or is it all or nothing for updating its elements/items.

Comment: The same way that you update a single cell in ListView, you can do the same in DataGridView, even better (using data-binding).

Comment: You should not remove the post, anyhow, in addition to Joan, maybe someone else also find it useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw yourself the [ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem) selected, owner-drawing the Control (set [`ListView.OwnerDraw = true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw)), then handle the `ListView.DrawSubItem` event.
The `ListView.DrawColumnHeader` event can use default values.

▶ I'm using [TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer) since this is the default renderer. If you use `Graphics.DrawText`, you'll notice the difference.

```
TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding |
                        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;

private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    var lv = sender as ListView;
    var subItem = lv.HitTest(lv.PointToClient(MousePosition)).SubItem;

    if (subItem != null && e.SubItem == subItem) {
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight)) {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.SubItem.Bounds);
        }
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, e.SubItem.Font, 
                              e.Bounds, SystemColors.HighlightText, flags);
    }
    else {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}

private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e) 
    => e.DrawDefault = true;

// Invalidate on a mouse interaction, otherwise the ListView doesn't redraw the SubItem
private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    => (sender as ListView).Invalidate();
```

---

Or, you can change the Colors of a SubItem when a mouse *interaction* is notified (here, using the `MouseDown` event) and save the previous state (just the Colors here). It's better to save the state because each SubItem can have it's own settings, so you cannot just revert back to the Parent ListViewItem or the ListView values.

As mentioned, set [`UseItemStyleForSubItems = false`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.useitemstyleforsubitems) in each parent ListViewItem, otherwise the Colors settings are ignored.
Also, [FullRowSelect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect) must be set to `false`, otherwise it's pointless :)

Here, the state is saved in a nullable named Tuple Field, `(ListViewSubItem, Color[])`.
A class object is probably better, this is just shorter.

```
private (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem Item, Color[] colors)? previousItem = null;

private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var lv = sender as ListView;
    var subItem = lv.HitTest(e.Location).SubItem;

    if (previousItem.HasValue) {
        // If an Item's Colors have been changed, restore the state
        // It removes the selection if you click in an empty area
        previousItem.Value.Item.BackColor = previousItem.Value.colors[0];
        previousItem.Value.Item.ForeColor = previousItem.Value.colors[1];
        lv.Invalidate(previousItem.Value.Item.Bounds);
    }

    if (subItem != null) {
        // Save the SubItem's colors state
        previousItem = (subItem, new[] { subItem.BackColor, subItem.ForeColor });
        // Set new Colors. Here, using the default highlight colors
        subItem.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
        subItem.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
        lv.Invalidate(subItem.Bounds);
    }
}
```

This is how this thing works:

[image: ListView SubItem Selection]

---

▶ About the Item / SubItem index, as it's mentioned in the question:

When you retrieve the `ListViewItem` / `SubItem` clicked with [ListView.HitTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.hittest)

```
 var hitTest = lv.HitTest(e.Location);
```

then the ListViewItem index is of course:

```
var itemIndex = hitTest.Item.Index;
```

and the `SubItem.Index` is:

```
var subItemIndex = hitTest.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hitTest.SubItem);
```