# Add a ComboBox To ListView Column in a Row?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Sometimes I want to add text to a ListView in an items column in a specific row.
Sometimes want to show a ComboBox for a user to select an entry.

Do I need to create a class derived from the ListView control?

Here is what I have so far:

```
ListView lv = new ListViewEx();
lv.Size = new Size(300, 300);
this.Controls.Add(lv);
lv.View = View.Details;
lv.FullRowSelect = true;
lv.Scrollable = true;

lv.Columns.Add("Column 1");
lv.Columns.Add("Column 2");
lv.Columns.Add("Column 3");
lv.Columns.Add("Column 4");

string[] testresult = new string[] { "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass" };
testresult = new string[] { "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass" };
ListViewItem itm;
itm = new ListViewItem(testresult);
lv.Items.Add(itm);

// need to add a ComboBox in the 4th column of this list view item and a way to get the value selected from it
testresult = new string[] { "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Click To Enter Pass/Fail Result" };
itm = new ListViewItem(testresult);
lv.Items.Add(itm);

    private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var lv = sender as ListView;
        var subItem = lv.HitTest(lv.PointToClient(MousePosition)).SubItem;

        if (subItem != null && e.SubItem == subItem)
        {
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.SubItem.Bounds);
            }

            if (e.SubItem.Text == "Click To Enter Pass/Fail Result")
            {
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, e.SubItem.Font,
                                      e.Bounds, SystemColors.HighlightText, flags);
            }
            else
            {
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, e.SubItem.Font,
                                      e.Bounds, SystemColors.HighlightText, flags);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A DataGridView would probably be more appropriate for this

Comment: You could use something like this: [How to get the selected SubItem index in a Listview and highlight it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65860374/7444103), to detect whether the SubItem is empty and place a ComboBox at the `subItem.Bounds` coordinates (instead or in addition to highlighting the content). -- I agree that using a DataGridView makes it simpler overall.

Comment: I tried a DataGridView but a ListView is better for my application, Any way Jimi you could show me how?

Comment: OK. I was able to add that method listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e) but how can I change that method to add a ComboBox in that cell when e.SubItem.Text == "Click To Enter Pass/Fail Result".  And also add a handler to get the result of the section chosen in the ComboBox. See updated code above.,

Answer (score 0):

I know linking to other sites is a always discouraged due to "link rot", but on the other hand it's not appropriate for me to copy and paste the entire document here as an answer.

Check out this guide from Microsoft : [Use a ComboBox control to edit data in a ListView control in Visual CSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/use-combobox-edit-listview)

Comment: That only applies to the first Column of a ListView. That's why I proposed that solution, in comments: to get the bounds of each sub-item, since, as you can see, the OP want to show a ComboBox in one or more sub-items, not necessarily just the first Column.

Comment: Indeed, but it's a good start  The base logic is there, with the hiding and showing of combobox, and the selection text, but you just have to use subitems instead, based on the column number being clicked :)

Comment: Yes, but you cannot, usually use the sub-items because you don't know what their bounds are. That's what the code i linked does. If you want to take it and adapt it to this question, that's quite fine.

Comment: The irony is that I found this question because I want to achieve the same thing :)  Combining your code with the example from MS could give me exactly what i need - thanks!