# Auto-Stretch ListView rows By Column Width

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listview with some rows, and all have a progressBar.

Adjusting column width works fine (as by design), however as it easily moves text within rows, it does NOT move the progressbar, resize it or even move it around.. without writing this:

```
private void fileList_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (CustomProgressBar p in fileList.Controls.OfType<CustomProgressBar>().ToList())
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                {
                    p.Width = fileList.Columns[3].Width;
                    p.Left = fileList.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width + 400;
                }
                else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
                {
                    p.Width = fileList.Columns[3].Width;
                    p.Left = fileList.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width + 227;
                }
            }
        }
```

I couldn't figure it out, so that was my only solution.. which "partially works".

**Initial - no resize yet**
[image]

**Column 1 resized**
[image]

**General column resizing (no particular order)**
[image]

Is there something I am missing about automatically aligning items correctly according to the column position or width?

The code I wrote has zero effect after the 2nd column, as I can not confirm if it is working correctly for column1/column2 to begin with. So I dont see a point implementing the rest of it, if its set to fail anyway.

Any help is appreciated.

.NET Framework 4.8 / WinForms

--

**NOTE:**
ProgressBar responds to all typical properties as would a regular progressBar. The difference is just the overlay shade and color. Nothing more.

Comment: A DataGridView makes it easier. You just need to handle paint event of the cell, or implement a custom DataGridViewProgressBarColumn. You can also rely on an owner-drawn ListView.

Comment: Due to investment in ListView, we need to use ListView. DataGridView is a different animal, and will take time to migrate things over that direction. ListView solutions are welcomed.

Comment: Each Column is related to a `ListViewSubItem` and a sub-item has a `Bounds` Property, which is the measure you need to place your Custom Controls (or draw them). See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65860374/7444103)

Comment: `p.Width = bounds.Width; p.Left = bounds.Left;` - This replaced all of my size logic and integers, already looking good!

Comment: What if the horizontal scrollbar shows up? You need to handle that as well to calculate  the `Left` and for the `ListView` you need to p/invoke `GetScrollInfo` function to get scrollbars info. Reza's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation on the code by Reza - that validates it completely for me, and that is exactly what I will do. Thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [OwnerDraw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the ListView to true. Then customize drawing of the sub items and for your specific column, draw a ProgressBar. To draw a ProgressBar, you can use [ProgressBarRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbarrenderer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or your own custom paint logic.

[image]

**Example**

The highlights of the code:

- Set the OwnerDraw = true.
- Handle DrawColumnHeaders and set e.DrawDefault = true.
- Handle DrawSubItems and for the progress column, draw a ProgressBar.
- Enable [DoubleBuffered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.doublebuffered?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) for the listview (in a derived class or using reflection).

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class ListViewProgressBarExample : Form
{
    private ListView listView1;
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        listView1 = new ListView();
        listView1.Columns.Add("#", 70);
        listView1.Columns.Add("File name", 200);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Progress", 400);
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
        listView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.DrawSubItem += listView1_DrawSubItem;
        this.Controls.Add(listView1);
        this.Text = "ListView ProgressBar Example";
        this.Size = new Size(800, 500);
        this.Load += ListViewProgressBarExample_Load;
    }
    public ListViewProgressBarExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
        listView1.GetType().GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
            .SetValue(listView1, true);
        listView1.DrawColumnHeader += (sender, e) => e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
    private void ListViewProgressBarExample_Load(object sender,
        EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "1", "lorem ipsum.txt", "10" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "2", "dolor sit.txt", "0" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "3", "amet.txt", "30" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "4", "consectetur adipiscing.txt", "70" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "5", "celit.txt", "50" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "6", "adipiscing elit.txt", "100" }));
    }
    private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, 
        DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            var r = e.Bounds;
            r.Inflate(-1, -1);
            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, r);
            r.Inflate(-1, -1);
            int w = r.Width * int.Parse(e.SubItem.Text) / 100;
            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalChunks(e.Graphics,
                new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, w, r.Height));
            e.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
                TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
        }
        else
            e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a gem! I added all this to a new project, compiled and it works as screenshot image. Very responsive and a lot better than my implementation! I am doing it all wrong I see, I will now begin to migrate to this code. Thank you!

Comment: Just for the future reference, in case someone cannot migrate their code and wants to keep using controls, I posted another answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on an owner-drawn ListView which I shared in my other answer is a better idea; however, just for the users who for any reason cannot change their solution, here is a solution based on adding ProgressBar controls to the Listview and adjusting control position based on sub-item position and size.

[image]

**Example**

Highlights of the code:

- You need to adjust control size, at least in the following events: [ColumnWidthChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.columnwidthchanged?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), [ColumnWidthChanging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.columnwidthchanging?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), [ColumnReordered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.columnreordered?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), [SizeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). There might be more.
- You also need to subclass ListView and handle MouseWheel, VerticalScroll and HorizontalScroll events. (By handling [WM_VSCROLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-vscroll?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), [WM_HSCROLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-hscroll?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), and [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousewheel?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) messages.)
- In the subclass, you need to hide the controls which are behind the header. (By sending [LVM_GETHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-getheader?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message and getting the header rectangle using [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).)
- When you adjust control position and size, you need to consider [AutoScrollPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) as well.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class ListViewProgressBarExample : Form
{
    private MyListView listView1;
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        listView1 = new MyListView();
        listView1.Columns.Add("#", 50);
        listView1.Columns.Add("File name", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Progress", 200);
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        Controls.Add(listView1);
        Text = "ListView ProgressBar Example";
        Size = new Size(500, 300);
    }
    public ListViewProgressBarExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "1", "lorem ipsum.txt", "10" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "2", "dolor sit.txt", "0" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "3", "amet.txt", "30" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "4", "consectetur adipiscing.txt", "70" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "5", "celit.txt", "50" }));
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            new[] { "6", "adipiscing elit.txt", "100" }));
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            var p = new ProgressBar();
            p.Value = int.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text);
            item.SubItems[2].Tag = p;
            if (p != null)
            {
                p.Bounds = item.SubItems[2].Bounds;
                listView1.Controls.Add(p);
                p.SendToBack();
            }
        }
        listView1.ColumnWidthChanged += (sender, args) => AdjustControls();
        listView1.ColumnReordered += (sender, args) => AdjustControls();
        listView1.ColumnWidthChanging += (sender, args) => AdjustControls();
        listView1.Scrolled += (sender, args) => AdjustControls();
        listView1.SizeChanged += (sender, args) => AdjustControls();
    }
    private void AdjustControls()
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems)
            {
                if (subItem.Tag is Control)
                {
                    var bound = subItem.Bounds;
                    bound.Offset(listView1.AutoScrollOffset);
                    var c = (Control)subItem.Tag;
                    c.Bounds = subItem.Bounds;
                    c.Visible = bound.Top >= listView1.GetHeaderHeight();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114;
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
    public event EventHandler Scrolled;
    private const int LVM_GETHEADER = 0x1000 + 31;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
        IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(
        IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);
    public int GetHeaderHeight()
    {
        var r = new RECT();
        var hwnd = SendMessage(Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (GetWindowRect(hwnd, out r))
            return r.Bottom - r.Top;
        return -1;
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
            Scrolled?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```